# Filter WIQL on the basis of linked parentId

Tags: azure-devops, wiql

In work item Query language, I need all the linked child tasks of the user story when I have the id of the user story.

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wiql Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor) and:

1. Create a new query to get your user story and linked child tasks:

[image]

2. Open the new query with the wiql editor

[image]

3. Then you can find WIQL:

[image]